# Error en atributo value de Select elimina palabras despues de espacios jquery js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy agregando una lista de países a un `option` `select` pero  me doy de cuenta que en el atributo `value` solo me asigna la primera palabra antes del espacio.

1. Esto es lo que estoy haciendo, creo un `select` vacío:

```
<select name="country" id="country" class="mdb-select md-form validate initialized" searchable="Select your country..." required="required" style="position: absolute; top: 1rem; left: 0px; height: 0px; width: 0px; opacity: 0; padding: 0px; pointer-events: none; display: inline!important;" tabindex="-1">
</select>
```

2. con **jQuery** agrego ciudades:

```
    var select = $('#country');

    país = "American Samoa"
    pais2 = "Colombia"

    select.append("<option  value=" + pais + ">" + pais + "</option>");
    select.append("<option  value=" + pais2 + ">" + pais2 + "</option>");
```

3. Acá nace el error en el `value` solo retorna la primer palabra de los países que contienen espacios, adjunto `select` final:

```
<select name="country" id="country" class="mdb-select md-form validate initialized" searchable="Select your country..." required="required" style="position: absolute; top: 1rem; left: 0px; height: 0px; width: 0px; opacity: 0; padding: 0px; pointer-events: none; display: inline!important;" tabindex="-1">
    <option value="American" samoa="" >American Samoa</option>
    <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
</select>
```

No entiendo a que se debe esto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El valor del atributo `option` es un `string` por lo cual te falta agregarle las comillas pertenecientes a dicho valor.

Al dejarlo sin comillas **HTML** entiende la primer palabra como el valor y la segunda como un nuevo atributo.

```js
var select = $('#country');

var pais = "American Samoa";
var pais2 = "Colombia";

select.append("<option value='" + pais + "'>" + pais + "</option>");
select.append("<option value='" + pais2 + "'>" + pais2 + "</option>");

select.change(function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="country" id="country" class="mdb-select md-form validate initialized" searchable="Select your country..." required="required" tabindex="-1"></select>
```

Comment: wow gracias men muy amable tu pronta respuesta

Comment: @NEFEGAGO Para eso estamos, la buena.

Comment: ¿Cómo se le llama a ese "metodo" de colocar comillas dobles dentro de simples?

Answer (score 3):

A pesar de que ya dieron respuesta te recomiendo realizar la concatenación con la forma propuesta en [ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings), de esta forma cortas menos el código, evitas este tipo de errores y trabajas más ordenado, adicional también te recomiendo poner todos los paises u opciones que van a poblar el select dentro de un array y luego iterarlo:

```js
var select = $('#country');

pais = "American Samoa";
pais2 = "Colombia";

select.append(`<option value="${pais}">${pais}</option>`);
select.append(`<option value="${pais2}">${pais2}</option>`);

//La mejor forma de poblar el select es iterando un listado de paises, así ahorras código y es más dinámico

var select2 = $('#country2');
paises = ["Canadá","Londres"];
for(pais of paises){
  select2.append(`<option value="${pais}">${pais}</option>`)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="country" id="country" class="mdb-select md-form validate initialized" searchable="Select your country..." required="required" style="" tabindex="-1">
</select>

<br> <br>

<select name="country2" id="country2" class="mdb-select md-form validate initialized" searchable="Select your country..." required="required" style="" tabindex="-1">
</select>
```

Comment: Gracias @jonathan-arias ya lo tuve en cuenta y lo aplique ammm puse los dos países en variable es porque estoy recorriendo un json y era para no pegar todo el json pero si tienes razon con lo de EcmaScript6.

Comment: Perfecto, cualquier duda me cuentas.